# ETL Performance Problem

Tags: sql-server, olap, etl

I have an important problem running ETL Process in production environment. While my ETL is running, the OLAP Server turns extremely slowly, I think this is because the ETL is updating several existing rows in the fact table and adding new ones. I tried to avoid this problem having a whole data base replication and ETL writes in DB1 and OLAP Server read from DB2(the replicated ones). It doesn't work at all.

Can you give me some advices which point me in the right solutions to avoid this problem.

I'm using SQL Server 2005. 8GB RAM
   Mondrian OLAP Server into a Jboss Server. 8GB RAM.
   ETL is running every 3 hours and is taking 2 hours running.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the ETL run it's process into a new table, then use ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH PARTITION to switch in the new data into the Facts table. See [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191160%28v=sql.105%29). I would also revisit the ETL itself, given that the one can [import about 2TB/hour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlperf/etl-world-record) with a well tuned ETL process, you can probably squeeze a bit more of performance yourself, I doubt you import 4TB every 3 hours...

As for the idea of using Replication to alleviate load problems, all I can say is this: Replication will always *add* to the load, as the replication process itself is *quite* expensive. Every insert, update, delete on the publisher is also an insert, update or delete on the subscriber, and there is the additional overhead of detecting changes on publisher, distribution overhead and applying changes on subscriber... is just going to add up, not subtract anything.